# Why do we have the C++14 tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

As it turns out, **my question is a duplicate of** [c++14 or c++1y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177625/157577)

---

We have the [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), but, according to its wiki we are not allowed to use it.

Then why have it in the first place? It only leads to confusion and repeated retaggings.

If we have it to signal that this tag should not be created (by someone who doesn't know about the C++1y tag) then could this be automated (by the Stack Exchange developers) or signaled in an other way?

---

UPDATE: OK, so apparently the only thing that needs to be done is to lock the C++14 tag (see  Mołot's comment right below). Also, Caleb states in his answer that moderators can block certain tags. How can I make that happen?

---

Excellent: the tag was deleted and recreated the next day. But this time the wiki was lost, forbidding the usage of the tag!

Comment: @Mołot Excellent. It's already created; how could I lock it / make it locked?

Comment: There's zero questions tagged with it; it'll go away during the next nightly cleanup routine provided that no more questions have the tag at that time.

Comment: Why not just make it a synonym of c++1y?

Comment: @LBT Perhaps the nightly cleanup isn't working properly. I believe there were longer time intervals than 1 day and this tag is still unchanged (its wiki).

Comment: @interjay Don't ask me :) I did not create the rule not to use the C++14 tag.

Comment: @Ali - or maybe it just keeps getting created and untagged.

Comment: @LBT That's why I think it should be locked.

Comment: @Ali There is no [tag locking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151920/add-the-ability-to-lock-tags). Tags can be blacklisted so they can't be created, which seems more logical anyway than having a tag that does exist but can't be used

Comment: @MichaelMrozek OK. Then why did Mołot say so (first comment)?  Caleb also says in his answer that moderators can block tags. I am getting confused at this point

Comment: @Ali Caleb is talking about blacklisting. You can blacklist a tag that exists, but it causes problems when people edit the post; it's usually only done to tags that don't exist, to prevent them from being created

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I am fine with blacklisting :) Or allowing the C++14 tag. I am not satisfied with the current situation: We have a tag that keeps popping up and we are NOT allowed to use it. I find the current situation, let's just say, weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this tag has **no** questions associated  with it.

It will be automatically removed [within the next 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags/40725#40725)

### Edit

[image: All hail Trogdor!]

Comment: I believe this is not the first time that there are no questions under it (for longer than 1 day), still, we have this tag with an unchanged Wiki. Perhaps the nightly cleanup isn't working properly. No idea...

Comment: Excellent, the tag was immediately recreated, we could not go even a day without it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14 still exists?

Comment: it was burninated because no valid question exist for that time. now has valid question and wiki details.

Comment: Does that count as burninating?

Answer (score 1):

Normally tags arrive when somebody with enough reputation slapps it on a question. Sometimes these end up being typos, perhaps they were trying to be cute, perhaps they thought that the extra tag actually mattered.

Also in general they usually go away as soon as 24 hours or so passes with no questions being tagged that way. Right now you have none, so it's well on its way to being obsolete. Once its gone, it will not show up in the tag completion suggestions box so it is unlikely to get used again.

For tags that do become problematic because people keep recreating them by tagging new questions but you are really sure need to stay-dead, the tags can be blocked by a moderator. This is usually only used in more extreme cases.

In the specific case of this tag, there appears to be more going on. The tag wiki makes reference to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177625/c14-or-c1y) where usage for the tag was hashed out. It is possible that the tag was created early by a moderator or site dev and is in some sort of locked state so that it doesn't go away (thus loosing the wiki explaining why it shouldn't be used yet).

The only question is now, why are you trying to get rid of it?

Comment: I believe this is not the first time that there are no questions under it (for longer than 1 day), still, we have this tag with an unchanged Wiki. Perhaps the nightly cleanup isn't working properly. No idea...

Comment: Because I keep bumping into this annoying tag. People keep using it and the wiki says do NOT use it. I cannot change the people so... :)